# Storing datas from online pages

Tags: python-3.x

AC is a list of accession numbers. AC = ['P02649\n','Q59297\', ...]
I would like to open the url corresponding to the accession number, and register all the data of each url into an other list (pdblines), each line should be an element of the list.

BUT my program below works only for the last accession number...

```
def recup_file(AC):
    for code in AC :
        code = code.strip()
        file = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/%s.txt" %code
        pdblines = str(urllib.request.urlopen(file).read()).split('\\n')
    return pdblines
```

How can I create a list of data for each number ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 0):

at each step of you for loop, the line `pdblines = str(urllib.request.urlopen(file).read()).split('\\n')` replaces the current value of `pdblines` with the new one.

What you want is probably a list containing all the values. So you have to:

1. declare an empty list before the loop
2. add the new value to the list at each loop step

try this:

```
def recup_file(AC):
    pdblines = []
    for code in AC :
        code = code.strip()
        file = "http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/%s.txt" %code
        pdblines.append(str(urllib.request.urlopen(file).read()).split('\\n'))
    return pdblines
```

Comment: Same issue unfortunately : it creates a list but only for the last accession number from my list AC : ['P02649\n','Q59297\', ...] so it creates a list pdblines only for Q59297... :(